# uwsgi flask server always return 'Hello World!'

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I follow this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-6-%E2%80%94-configuring-nginx-to-proxy-requests) to configure nginx and uwsgi.

Here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myprojetc` content:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.x.x.my_server_ip;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/myname/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Now I can visit `10.x.x.my_server_ip` on my laptop browser. And it shows me: `Hello World!`.

However myproject.py is:

```
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)


@application.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello There'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

As you see, it's expected to return `Hello There`. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my configuration? If you need more info, you can comment.

Comment: Did you change the return message or it was already “Hello There” at the beginning? Any change to the source code will require restarting the service since debug mode if off.

Comment: @metmirr Af first it's actually returns `Hello World`. Then I changed it. I have execute `sudo systemctl restart nginx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long days, I found solution where I have to restart uwsgi service instead of restarting nginx.